# How to filter using Grafana queries

Tags: prometheus, grafana

So I have a `grafana` dashboard and I need to filter out some labels. So I am using `label_values` function.

My data source is `prometheus`

So, to this `label_values` function, i am passing a variable `domain_name` and it produces 3 results as:

```
domain1
domain2
domain3
```

But I need to only filter and get the `domain1`, so `domain2` and `domain3` are removed.

So I tried these and it says expressions are invalid.

```
// 1 method, gives invalid expression error
label_values(domain_name)[0]

// 2 method, gives invalid expression error
label_values(domain_name[0])
```

So How can I do this?

Here attached a screenshot as well.

[image]

Comment: Please consider checking out a basic tutorial on Prometheus / Grafana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit hard to understand. So here are two answers:

**You want only `domain1` to end up in the template variable:**

`label_values(my_metric{my_label="domain1"}, my_label)`

I cannot imagine a reason why you would want this. So I assume you actually want to filter your dashboard / panels for this specific domain.

**You want to filter dashboard / panels for a specific domain:**

`label_values(my_metric_that_has_label_with_all_domains, domain_label_name)`

Don't forget to set update on time range change.

Now in a panel you can use the variable like this:

`rate(mymetric{domain_label_name=~"$cluster"}[5m])`

---

Examplary usage

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you tell me how did you end up with the variables such as `domain_label_name`, `cluster`, `my_label` ?

Comment: My requirement is, there are 3 clusters showing up in drop down menu in the dashboard.  so I want to show only one cluster called `domain1`

Comment: in your last example: `label_values(my_metric_that_has_label_with_all_domains, domain_label_name)` this is how the currentt setup is and that is how it shows 3 clusters in the dashboard. This is how I set is as your last example. `label_values(aws_es_nodes_average, domain_name)`, but it gives `3` results (`domain1`, `domain2`, `domain3`). I want to only show `domain1`

Comment: Just to understand you right, you want the drop down to only contain `domain1` or select `domain1` from the dropdown with all options and then have all panels in the dashboard query for `domain1`. You use the variables in panels like so `aws_es_nodes_average{domain_name=~"$name_of_the_variable_you_created"}`

Comment: i am kind of shocked, can you give me the complete query for this?

Comment: Sir, what I want to do is, where it says, datasource, in your example, it is a dropdown with multiple items. right? So what I need to do is, i need to show only one item in that dropdown. How can I do that? let's say we want to show only the item `biomap`, how can you change your variables then?

Comment: So you want the variable to only contain a single value but at the same time you cannot hard code this single value? In Grafana you could also select the specific value and then hide the variable in the settings. This way the variable won't be shown in the bar. And then you could reference this variable in another (constant) variable.

Comment: no no, i can hardcode. it is no problem. what i am saying this, in your example, you have multiple data sources in that drop down. If someone asks you to, please I need only this one data source to show in this drop down, how would you do it.

Comment: Okay thank you it worked, i used your example `label_values(my_metric{my_label="domain1"}, my_label)`